# How to retrieve a data from API or Firebase before rendering anything to the user in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-redux

I want to retrieve data from Firebase and then update it to redux and render it to the user. Can we have conditional rendering in `App.js`?

If am retrieving a data in `HomePage.js` (a component) and updating it to redux and displaying it. Then when the user navigates to another page `Orders.js` or `MyProfile.js` I get the data from redux using `useSelector` and displaying it. But if the user visits a `Orders.js` or `MyProfile.js` first the data is not retrieved yet since the user didn't visit `HomePage.js`.

I can now retrieve the data in App.js and use conditional rendering to hold the user from viewing other screen by rendering a loading screen. Is this a good practice?

How to get data universally for all pages before rendering anything to the user?. Hope I made the question clear.

Comment: You are describing Higher Order Components and you should investigate how to architect them for your purposes. Delaying any output to the user is considered an  anti-pattern and is the entire reason for data-binding to exist in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's completely good practice. Since if there's no any indicator of loading then user might thought that his/her data is deleted. If the app requires that data to make it intractable for user, then the wait is necessary.

You can use conditional rendering like ...
`data !== undefined ? renderStuff() : loadingIndicator()`

You can use [react-activity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-activity) for animated loading indicators.

You can get all your data in main component like `App` and use `useEffect` hook to call the server for data. you can use [async Actions](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic) to call APIs.

Hope this answered you questions.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the best practice is to load the page anyway regardless of whether the data is ready. Yet, in case the data is NOT ready, display the `skeleton` of the page similar to this:
[image]

Then fetch the data in the `useEffect` hook and do a `setState` once the data is received. After that, display the intended component.

e.g.

```
const Videos = () => {
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState(new Array(5));
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/videos')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(videos => setVideos(videos))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false))
  }, []);

  return (
    <Container>
      {videos.map(video => loading
        ? <Skeleton />
        : <Video video={video} />
      )}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Note, with the upcoming concurrent mode (no ETA yet, but it has been discussed for a long time). The practice will be changed drastically.